# "Gridview Images" and "Full screen" fragments in multi pane(android)

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments, pane

I'm new android..my english little bit:(
I want develop multi pane app.
Two fragments **"Gridview"** and **"Full screen"** 
I know multi pane, but i dont know Gridview and Full screen in multi pane.
Because all samples for ListView.
help me please

this app good for me but too complex=
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/779293/Building-Dynamic-UI-for-Android-Devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a simple implementation if i understand your question correctly

------------- Creating GridView ------------

1. For GridView you need an adapter for your GridView Object and images for columns, an example using country list and flag images,

Create drawable folder inside res and add country flag images inside drawable folder

2. Create gridlayout.xml in res/layout

   ```
      <RelativeLayout  
       android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:background="@drawable/border"
       android:padding="5dp">

       <ImageView 
       android:id="@+id/gridimage" 
       android:layout_height="65dp" 
           android:layout_width="65dp" 
           android:src="@drawable/icon" 
           android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
       </ImageView>

       <TextView 
           android:id="@+id/gridtext"
           android:text="TextView" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1" 
           android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:textSize="18sp"
           android:ellipsize="marquee"></TextView>

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```
3. Create gridrow.xml in res/Layout folder

   ```
   <GridView 
       android:id="@+id/gridView1" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_width="match_parent" 
       android:numColumns="auto_fit"
       android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
       android:verticalSpacing="10dp">
   </GridView>
   ```
4. Create GridAdapter.java class

   ```
   public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter { 
       private ArrayList<String> CountryList;
               private ArrayList<Integer> CountryFlag;
               private Activity activity;
               public GridAdapter(Activity activity,ArrayList<String> CountryList, ArrayList<Integer> CountryFlag){
   super();this.CountryList = CountryList;
               this.CountryFlag = CountryFlag;
               this.activity = activity;}
       @Override
           public int getCount() {
               return CountryList.size();
           }

           @Override
           public String getItem(int position) {
               return CountryList.get(position);
           }

           @Override
           public long getItemId(int position) {
               return 0;
           }

           public static class ViewHolder
           {
               public ImageView imgViewFlag;
               public TextView txtViewTitle;
           }

           @Override
           public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
               ViewHolder view;
               LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();

               if(convertView==null)
               {
                   view = new ViewHolder();
                   convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.gridview_row, null);

                   view.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gridtext);
                   view.imgViewFlag = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gridimage);

                   convertView.setTag(view);
               }
               else
               {
                   view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
               }

               view.txtViewTitle.setText(CountryList.get(position));
               view.imgViewFlag.setImageResource(CountryFlag.get(position));

               return convertView;
           }
   ```

   }

   5. Create Fragment GridViewActivty

   `public class GridViewActivty extends Fragment {
     private ArrayList CountryList = new ArrayList();
     private ArrayList CountryFlag = new ArrayList();
     private GridView mygrid;
     private GridAdapter adapter;
       private Context context;
       public GridViewActivty(){}
       @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
   ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
           { View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridlayout.xml, container, false);`

   ```
             CountryList = new ArrayList<String>();
             CountryList.add("South Africa");
             CountryList.add("Spain");
             CountryList.add("Canada");
             CountryList.add("China");
             CountryList.add("France");
             CountryList.add("Germany");
             CountryList.add("Iran");
             CountryList.add("Italy");
             CountryList.add("Japan");
             CountryList.add("Korea");
             CountryList.add("Mexico");  
             CountryList.add("Netherlands");
             CountryFlag = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                 CountryFlag.add(R.drawable.southafrica);
                 CountryFlag.add(R.drawable.spain);
                 CountryFlag.add(R.drawable.canada);
                 CountryFlag.add(R.drawable.china);
                 CountryFlag.add(R.drawable.france);
                 CountryFlag.add(R.drawable.germany);
                 CountryFlag.add(R.drawable.iran);
                 CountryFlag.add(R.drawable.italy);
                 CountryFlag.add(R.drawable.japan);
                 CountryFlag.add(R.drawable.korea);
                 CountryFlag.add(R.drawable.mexico);
                 CountryFlag.add(R.drawable.netherlands);
                adapter = new GridAdapter(this.getActivity(),CountryList, CountryFlag);

           mygrid = (GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview1);

           mygrid.setAdapter(adapter);
           mygrid.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
           {
               @Override
               public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                       long arg3) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

               }
           }
                   );
           return rootView;

           }

   }
   ```

   ```
   ----------- Creating Full Screen --------
   ```
5. Create fullscreen.xml inside Layout Folder

   ```
       <RelativeLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
   </RelativeLayout>
   ```

   >
6. Create FullScreen.java Fragment

   ```
    public class Fullscreen extends Fragment{    @Override    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle 
            savedInstanceState)    
   { View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fullscreen.xml, container, false);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

           getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,

            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

               }

           return convertView; }
   ```

Comment: i think stackoverflow codeblock has a problem or is it my code that doesn't want to be in form @codeblock ?

Comment: thanks for your help..but how i make these fragments into Multi pane layout (tablet, handset).
I hope I could explain better.

Comment: So how do I put this
fragments in multi pane layout(tablet handset)?

as this= http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html

Comment: i will check on my codes 2 years ago i coded a sliding multipane fragments, but you said you knew multipane?

Comment: I know multi pane with ListView but I dont know with GridView..
Fragment1 Grirview Fragment2 Full Screen.In Dual Pane.
but I dont know how

Comment: this app good for me but too complex= http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/779293/Building-Dynamic-UI-for-Android-Devices

Comment: Here is Multipane source code - https://github.com/Altiano/MultipaneFragments and here is a video link for in case if you get lost https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Rjkv2-saDk , get back to me if you get any problems with this

Comment: first **thanks** your helps, really.. I'm not use in **eclipse** yet.no errors in eclipse but stopped in emulator..how can i change **gradle project** to **eclipse project**?